# The Instance of Entity Type 'Assignment' Cannot Be Tracked While Seeding Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm new to Entity Framework Core, and have had trouble seeding a mssql database. I have a Subject model and a Assignment model with a one to many relationship (Subject has a ICollection).

I tried adding:

```
storeContext.Entry<Subject>(subject1).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

for all the objects created for the database, but it still gave the same error.

I get this error when trying to run the asp.net core application:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
The instance of entity type 'Assignment' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'AssignmentId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

The DatabaseInitializer class:

```
using FoxAcademicManager.Backend.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FoxAcademicManager.Backend.Data
{
    public class DatabaseInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            using (var scope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AcademicManagerContext>();

                //do your stuff....
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                if (context.Subjects.Any()) return;
                if (context.Events.Any()) return;
                var subject1 = new Subject
                {
                    SubjectId = 1,
                    Title = "Physics",
                    Description = "The AB Physics course",
                    GradeEarned = null,
                    GradeOverall = null,

                };

                var subject2 = new Subject
                {
                    SubjectId = 2,
                    Title = "Chemistry",
                    Description = "A AB Chem course",
                    GradeEarned = null,
                    GradeOverall = null,

                };

                var assignment1 = new Assignment
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0),
                    Name = "Assignment 1",
                    Description = "Forces and Newton's Laws of Motion",
                    Score = 80,
                    Weight = 0.2,
                    AssignmentId = 1,
                    SubjectId = 1
                };

                var assignment2 = new Assignment
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0),
                    Name = "Assignment 2",
                    Description = "Gravity",
                    Score = 90,
                    Weight = 0.2,
                    AssignmentId = 2,
                    SubjectId = 1
                };

                var assignment3 = new Assignment
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0),
                    Name = "Assignment 3",
                    Description = "Frequency",
                    Score = 70,
                    Weight = 0.2,
                    AssignmentId = 3,
                    SubjectId = 1
                };

                var exam1 = new Assignment
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2020, 5, 1, 10, 0, 0),
                    Name = "Exam 1",
                    Description = "The first exam",
                    Score = 85,
                    Weight = 0.6,
                    AssignmentId = 1,
                    SubjectId = 2
                };

                var exam2 = new Assignment
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2020, 6, 1, 11, 0, 0),
                    Name = "Exam 2",
                    Description = "The second exam",
                    Score = 75,
                    Weight = 0.6,
                    AssignmentId = 2,
                    SubjectId = 2
                };

                var assignmentz1 = new Assignment
                {
                    Date = new DateTime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 0, 0),
                    Name = "Assignment 1",
                    Description = "The first Chem grade",
                    Score = 85,
                    Weight = 0.2,
                    AssignmentId = 3,
                    SubjectId = 2
                };

                context.Subjects.AddRange(new Subject[] { subject1, subject2 });
                subject1.Assignments = new List<Assignment> { assignment1, assignment2, assignment3 };
                subject2.Assignments = new List<Assignment> { exam1, exam2, assignmentz1 };
                context.UpdateRange(subject1, subject2);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Startup.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using FoxAcademicManager.Backend.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace FoxAcademicManager.Backend
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); 
            services.AddDbContext<AcademicManagerContext>               
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Academic Manager", Version = "v1"})
            );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();

            if(env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsStaging())
            {
                app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Academic Manager v1")
                );
            }

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
            DatabaseInitializer.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `AssignmentId` a PK (primary key) of `Assignment`? If yes (as it seems), it should be unique. And your seed data contains duplicate `AssignmentId`s - for instance, `assignment1` and `exam1` have `AssignmentId == 1`. You should probably let the database generate these ids. Same for `Subject`. You'd basically need to create the `Subject` objects with populated `Assignments` collections (don't specify hardcoded PKs and FKs) and then simply do `context.Subjects.AddRange(…)` - EF Core will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For initializing database with EF Context, you could not set the key for entity directly, it is generated automatically.

Try to make a test with code below:

1. Model `Subject`

   ```
   public class Subject
   {
       public int SubjectId { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public string GradeEarned { get; set; }
       public string GradeOverall { get; set; }
       public List<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Model `Assignment`

   ```
   public class Assignment
   {
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public int Score { get; set; }
       public double Weight { get; set; }
       public int AssignmentId { get; set; }
       public int SubjectId { get; set; }
       public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Seed database

   ```
   public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
       using (var scope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
       {
           var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

           //do your stuff....
           context.Database.EnsureCreated();
           var subject1 = new Subject
           {
               Title = "Physics",
               Description = "The AB Physics course",
               GradeEarned = null,
               GradeOverall = null,
           };

           var subject2 = new Subject
           {
               Title = "Chemistry",
               Description = "A AB Chem course",
               GradeEarned = null,
               GradeOverall = null,
           };

           var assignment1 = new Assignment
           {
               Date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0),
               Name = "Assignment 1",
               Description = "Forces and Newton's Laws of Motion",
               Score = 80,
               Weight = 0.2,
               Subject = subject1
           };

           var assignment2 = new Assignment
           {
               Date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0),
               Name = "Assignment 2",
               Description = "Gravity",
               Score = 90,
               Weight = 0.2,
               Subject = subject1
           };

           var assignment3 = new Assignment
           {
               Date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0),
               Name = "Assignment 3",
               Description = "Frequency",
               Score = 70,
               Weight = 0.2,
               Subject = subject1
           };

           var exam1 = new Assignment
           {
               Date = new DateTime(2020, 5, 1, 10, 0, 0),
               Name = "Exam 1",
               Description = "The first exam",
               Score = 85,
               Weight = 0.6,
               Subject = subject2
           };

           var exam2 = new Assignment
           {
               Date = new DateTime(2020, 6, 1, 11, 0, 0),
               Name = "Exam 2",
               Description = "The second exam",
               Score = 75,
               Weight = 0.6,
               Subject = subject2
           };

           var assignmentz1 = new Assignment
           {
               Date = new DateTime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 0, 0),
               Name = "Assignment 1",
               Description = "The first Chem grade",
               Score = 85,
               Weight = 0.2,
               Subject = subject2
           };

           context.Subjects.AddRange(new Subject[] { subject1, subject2 });
           context.Assignments.AddRange(new Assignment[] { assignment1, assignment2, assignment3, exam1, exam2 });
           context.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
   ```

   If you insist on inserting the value for `id`, you could try `modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData` and you could refer [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)